# Trying to read integers from a .txt file and store them in a 2D array

Tags: c++, file-io, multidimensional-array

The problem is that I can't get the values to save into the indexed points of the array. When I attempt to print the 2D array, it prints in the correct format, but I just get crazy numbers instead of the ones from the text file. This leads me to believe that my function to fill the array is not working properly, but I'm having trouble diagnosing where the problem is.

Here is my function to fill the array.

```
void fill2dArray(int array[][4], int size, int& numberUsed)
{
ifstream recordsFile;
int index1, index2;

recordsFile.open("data11.txt");

while ((index1 < size) && (!recordsFile.eof()))
{
    for (index1 = 0; index1 < size; index1 = index1 + 1)
        for(index2 = 0; index2 < 4; index2 = index2 + 1)
            recordsFile >> array[index1][index2];

}
numberUsed = index1;
recordsFile.close();
}
```

Here is my function to print the array.

```
void print2dArray(const int array[][4], int numberUsed)
{
int index1, index2;

for (index1 = 0; index1 < numberUsed; index1 = index1 + 1)
{
    for (index2 = 0; index2 < 4; index2 = index2 + 1)
        cout << array[index1][index2] << " ";

    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Here is the globals/prototypes

```
const int NOP = 25; //Max number of players in the records file

void fill2dArray(int array[][4], int size, int& numberUsed);
void print2dArray(const int array[][4], int numberUsed);
```

Here is the main

```
int main()
{
int records[NOP][4], numberUsed;

fill2dArray(records, NOP, numberUsed);

print2dArray(records, numberUsed);


return 0;
}
```

And the text file (stored in the same folder as the program)

```
1 2 1 1
2 3 2 3
3 2 3 1
4 0 3 4
5 2 1 3
6 5 2 5
7 2 4 2
8 4 1 0
9 0 2 3
10 1 4 3
11 2 3 1
12 3 5 6
13 2 3 5
14 2 1 0
15 2 1 4
16 7 3 5
17 9 3 2
18 6 2 1
19 3 2 0
20 1 0 0
21 0 0 0
22 1 2 5
23 2 4 2
24 6 2 7
25 6 2 4
```

Comment: That's a typical case for using a debugger.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Also `while ((index1 < size) && (!recordsFile.eof()))`, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: You start your program in a debugger, step through single lines of code and watch how the variables are changing.

Comment: show your specific output.

Comment: Thanks TTAVTA, I did not know that about EOF!

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the `fill2dArray`, you define `index1` but don't assign any value to it, so it's undefined, it may be less than `size` or more than `size`.

Simply assign 0 to `index1` variable, at the beginning.

Comment: I tried this but still getting uninitialized values in the output. I've rewritten the function to where I manually input values into the array, and it will print fine. That leads me to believe there is a problem with the text file I'm using to test with. The file is located in a folder off of my desktop co-located with the program. I'm going to try and see if there is anything weird going on within the .txt file itself.

Comment: @Victor I ran your code and it worked for me, so feel free to ask more if you find something new

Comment: I figured out the problem. The text file was named data11.txt... which I guess the program was reading it as data11.txt.txt. Sigh.. Thanks for the help everyone!